# Google map api is it possible to get a list of all US administrative_area_level_2 latitude/longitude

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is is possible to get a list of all the longitude/latitudes pairs of all administrative_area_level_2 "regions" in the USA for the Google map API?

I could go a poll with a http get (as below) every inch of the USA and extract every administrative_area_level_2 returned, but there has got to be a better way :)

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=39.714224,-99.961452&sensor=true

Answer (score 0):

You want a list of all the counties in the US.

```
administrative_area_level_2 indicates a second-order civil entity below the country level. Within the United States, these administrative levels are counties. Not all nations exhibit these administrative levels.
```

That data is available in FusionTables (but it is the county polygon not a single point):

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=0IMZAFCwR-t7jZnVzaW9udGFibGVzOjIxMDIxNw#map:id=17

It is also available from the census:
http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_counties.html

Comment: Cool, now how do I get the longitude and latitude (like the one returned by the googlemap api call above?

Comment: You can calculate it from that data.